# Loading a cci file in R

Tags: r, cci

Situation: I want to load a .cci file in `R` like this:

```
data <- read.table("data.cci", header = T, dec = ".")
```

I also tried read.csv/read.csv2 - but I always get this error:

```
No such file or directory
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

Thanks for considering this question.

P.S. the WD is fine

Comment: Clearly the working directory is not fine, since R is telling you that the file is not there.

Comment: Double checked it - I am sure the wd is ok.

Comment: Really? You checked what files are in your current directly with `list.files()` and it was there? There aren't that many other ways to get that message.

Comment: If R can't open the connection, either you're not in the right directory or the file has the wrong permissions. What shows up when you run `dir()`? Also, I'm curious about your file format: .cci is that an old nintendo file? If it is, I don't think R will be able to parse it.

Comment: I found the mistake in the meantime - the file was saved with the wrong ending ".cci" - indeed it's a plain ."csv". Thx for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is your file and working directory is in different folder. 
You can get wd with

```
getwd()
```

and than write the correct location like. (pay attention to " / " not " \ " )

```
data <- read.table("C:/files/data.cci", header = T, dec = ".")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - but the linked WD is fine

Comment: I would try to write full file location explicitly